# Should these services, including Tor, be starting at shutdown?

Tags: 18.04, shutdown, services, tor, thunderbolt

Lately when I shutdown my computer it takes a long time to power down, and on at least two occasions it has actually stayed on after the screen goes black (LEDs and fans still operating). So I started hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> immediately after clicking Power Off, and this is what I see:

```
/dev/nvme2n1p2: clean, X/Y files, X/Y blocks.
[ OK ] Created slice User Slice of gdm.
Starting User Manager for UID 121…
[ OK ] Started Session c1 of user gdm.
[ OK ] Started User Manager for UID 121.
Starting Daemon for power management…
[ OK ] Started Daemon for power management.
[ OK ] Started Snappy daemon.
Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded…
[ OK ] Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
Starting RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service…
[ OK ] Started RealtimeKit Scheduling Policy Service.
Starting Locale Service…
[ OK ] Started Anonymizing overlay network for TCP.
[ OK ] Started Locale Service.
Starting Location Lookup Service…
Starting Thunderbolt system service…
[ OK ] Started Location Lookup Service.
Starting PackageKit Daemon…
[ OK ] Started PackageKit Daemon.
[ OK ] Started Thunderbolt system service.
```

This disk partition isn't visible using GParted, and I think one of the services is Tor. Is this normal to see at shutdown? I don't want to jump to any conclusions or get paranoid about things that I admittedly don't fully grasp yet. Any knowledge is appreciated.